# How to mapping subdomain to port on Nginx?

Tags: nginx

In our system, each tenant has their own page at specific port:

```
Tenant 1000 -> https://[ip]:1000
Tenant 1001 -> https://[ip]:1001
Tenant 1xxx -> https://[ip]:1xxx
```

Now we want access to these instances via subdomain:

```
https://t1000.mydomain.com
https://t1001.mydomain.com
https://t1xxx.mydomain.com
```

So my question is: how to config Nginx to map subdomain into port dynamically?

```
https://t1000.mydomain.com -> https://[ip]:1000
https://t1001.mydomain.com -> https://[ip]:1001
https://t1xxx.mydomain.com -> https://[ip]:1xxx
```

Answer (score 1):

I finally found a way to do this:

```
server {
    listen 80;

    server_name ~^t(?<port>[^.]+)\.mydomain\.com$;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:$port;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }
}
```